# AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) and SQL

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nat, azure-application-gateway, azure-front-door

We have built an AKS cluster with various pods to suit our architecture. One of those pods is a SQL Server, the SQL provides the back end store for an API but we have a requirement to expose read only access to that SQL Server over the internet to provide access to PowerBI. We also want to be able to control the access to this SQL via a firewall to restrict access, provide DDOS etc - what would be our options for locking down the cluster but still providing secure access to the SQL? We have tried Application Gateway but have not managed a successful set up. Could someone point us in the right direction?

I know we can use a PowerBI Gateway, but that requires a virtual machine and that requires additional maintenance and infrastructure so is option #2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an Application Gateway because it's layer 7 and only work with HTTP. I don't know what else is in your cluster and if they are exposed publicly but one option would be to use a [Public Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard) that only expose the SQL Pod and use [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) on your cluster Subnet to restrict the traffic coming from the Internet. You can add [Azure DDoS Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-overview) on your VNet if you think it is needed, but it is expensive.